# effect of linear term on quadratic programming

Tags: optimization, quadratic-form, operations-research

What's the impact of linear term ($d$) on quadratic programming problem ($P$) described as follows
\begin{align*}
\min_x d^T x + 1/2 x^T D x\\
\text{such that }A^T x \geq x_0
\end{align*}

where $D$ is symmetric positive definite matrix.
In other words, how can i interpret this? how can evaluate the effect of linear term on the convergence of quadratic optimization? is that influence on the computation of the method.

what the effect on resolving the problem $P$ when $d$ is represented by a vector of zeros, by a vector of ones or $d$ takes random values.

Comment: What happens to your problem after you [complete the square](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1011192)?

Comment: $d$ can affect the optimal value of $x$, i.e., the argmin, as well as the optimal value of the objective function, and even, potentially, whether the objective function is bounded.. $d$ can not affect feasibility, unless it also appears in constraint(s). $d$ does contribute to the gradient of the objective. $d$ does not contribute to the Hessian of the objective, and has no effect on whether the objective is convex, indefinite, or concave, which is solely determined by $D$.

Comment: can one deduce that $d$ influence on the convergence time to reach the minimum of a function

Comment: Starting from what point?  Using what algorithm?